# TypeError: Fetch argument 12434120.0 has invalid type <class 'numpy.float32'>, must be a string or Tensor. (in Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm training a Multiple linear regression model, and this error code appeared.

```
TypeError: Fetch argument 12434120.0 has invalid type <class 'numpy.float32'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a float32 into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

I wonder what this means...
and the training code is like this:

```
for step in range(100001):
    cost_, hypo_, _ = sess.run([cost, hypothesis, train], feed_dict={X: x_data,Y: y_data})
    if step % 500 == 0:
        print('#', step, 'loss:', cost_))
        print('-price of cabbage:', hypo_[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the kernel, and it suddenly works... I think the problem was the duplication of the names 'cost', so I changed it into 'cost_'